# Is it possible to patent a product designed entirely with computer simulations?

Tags: patent-applications, physics, engineering, mathematical-computations

I have designed a product called a Metamaterial that absorbs acoustic waves at broadband frequencies. The design is novel and demonstrated entirely through physics-based simulation software (Comsol). The software models the geometry (dimensions),  material models, and physics of acoustics and proves the absorption of acoustic waves.

The novelty is in the geometry of the product, which gives a broadband performance.

Is it possible to patent this? That is without any physical demonstration. The design can be 3d printed as well and proven with physical experiments.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible to patent an invention without creating a physical example. I have at least one patent like that. As long as the invention meets the requirements of novelty, non-obviousness and utility it is eligible.

That said, there are advantages to experimental results. For one, physics simulations are always approximations of reality and are best used with confirmation experiments. Also, you want to patent as broadly as possible otherwise someone may be able to design around your claims. Experimentation can help provide data to establish useful ranges.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree that simulations plus physical experiments is the best way to demonstrate. But at the moment I have limited resources to conduct an experiment. My idea was to apply for a patent then publication, then I can look at attracting some investors so that I may commercialise the idea. Do you feel this is ok?

Comment: @Arn What some people do is file a provisional application which gives them a year to file their non provisional application.  I’d avoid publishing since you might want to file internationally. You can discuss your invention with investors with confidentiality agreements in place.